# Appropriate referencing of dynamically generated of arrays in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying - New at PHP.  I looked but cannot figure this out - I may not have the vocabulary to search appropriately...

Instead of hard coding topics like Cardiology, Dermatology, etc, I was trying to create a dynamic variable array that I could use instead.  I was planning on putting them into an array, but the problem I'm having is with regard to parsing the name appropriately.

Example:

```
$cardsstatsstddevall =  $topicassocstring.['StandardDeviation'];
```

I want to dynamically generate the $topicassocstring.['StandardDeviation'].

Tried some different things:

```
$TopicFull='Cardiology';
$TopicShort='cards';
$topicassocstring =  '$'."{$TopicShort}".'statsassoc';
$topicassoc = $topicassocstring;
$topicstddev =  "{$topicassoc}"."['StandardDeviation']";
```

Code block:

```
$cardsstats =  mysqli_query($con, "SELECT STDDEV_SAMP({$TopicFull}Percent) AS StandardDeviation, VARIANCE({$TopicFull}Percent) As Variance, AVG({$TopicFull}Percent) As Average FROM residentpagers WHERE {$TopicFull}Percent != 0 AND PGY !=99;");
$cardsstatsassoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cardsstats);
$cardsstatsstddevall =  $cardsstatsassoc['Standard Deviation'];
$cardsstatsvarianceall = $cardsstatsassoc['Variance'];
$cardsstatsaverageall = $cardsstatsassoc['Average'];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be mixing/confusing a few different concepts in your examples:

**#1** - Associative array keys are just strings, and referencing supports expressions:

```
$fruitValues = ['apple' => 123, 'banana' => 456, 'orange' => 789];

$fruit = 'apple';

$fruitValues[$fruit]; // int(123) - same as $fruitValues['apple']
```

Here, `$fruit` holds the string `"apple"`, which is used as the array key (`$fruitValues[$fruit]` is the same as `$fruitValues["apple"]`).

**#2** - Variable names can be dynamic (sometimes referred to as variable variables):

```
$apple = 123;

$fruit = 'apple';

$$fruit; // int(123) - same as $apple
```

Here, the `$fruit` variable holds the string `"apple"`, which is used as the name of the variable (`$$fruit` is the same as `${"apple"}` is the same as `$apple`).

**#3** - Variable names support expressions:

```
$apple = 123;

$foo = 'ap';
$bar = 'ple';

${$foo . $bar}; // int(123) - same as $apple
```

Here, the strings in `$foo` and `$bar` are concatenated to for the string `"apple"`, which is then used as the name of the variable (`${$foo . $bar}` is the same as `${"ap" . "ple"}` is the same as `${"apple"}` is the same as `$apple`).

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for: 
`${$foo . $bar}`
Thank you very much!